# XPath: Default to "Master" node, select current node if specified (in third node)

Tags: xpath, conditional-operator, infopath2010

My problem:

- I need to select the value in the "Master_Node" only if the "Sub_Node_Checker" is set to "false".
- If "Sub_Node_Checker" is set to "true" then the value must be set to "Sub_Node".
- Current node is "Sub_Node"
- I am using InfoPath 2010.

Here is my sample XML:

```
<my:myFields xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2013-07-02T14:58:05" xml:lang="en-us">
<my:Master_Node>123456</my:Master_Node>
<my:Repeater>
    <my:Sub_Node_Checker>false</my:Sub_Node_Checker>
    <my:Sub_Node></my:Sub_Node>
</my:Repeater>
</my:myFields>
```

Refer to [the following forum thread](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/26222/91044.aspx#91044) to download my XSN template.

Here is the XPath that I have been attempting to use, to no avail (line breaks added for legibility):

```
//my:Master_Node[../my:Sub_Node_Checker = "false"] 
|
../my:Sub_Node[../my:Sub_Node_Checker = "true"]
```

This does not seem to return anything whatsoever, and I'm not sure why.

The following question accompanies "Sub_Node_Checker" in my XML form: "Does the sub node differ from the master node?"

- If the user selects "Yes" (true) then the Sub_Node field should be set to its own value.
- If the user selects "No" (false) then the Sub_Node field should default to the Master_Node.

**Edit & Additional XML**

My `Repeater` section repeats (as per the name) and seems to cause additional chaos with the XPath selectors.

```
<my:myFields xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2013-07-02T14:58:05" xml:lang="en-us">
<my:Master_Node>123123</my:Master_Node>
<my:Repeater>
    <my:Sub_Node_Checker>false</my:Sub_Node_Checker>
    <my:Sub_Node></my:Sub_Node>
</my:Repeater>
<my:Repeater>
    <my:Sub_Node_Checker>false</my:Sub_Node_Checker>
    <my:Sub_Node></my:Sub_Node>
</my:Repeater>
</my:myFields>
```

Answer (score 1):

A much cleaner solution would be to move the predicate to the `<my:myFields/>` element.

```
/my:myFields[my:Repeater/my:Sub_Node_Checker = "false"]/my:Master_Node
```

If you insist on your approach, you're missing a `/` to jump over the `<my:Repeater/>` element or reference that:

```
//my:Master_Node[..//my:Sub_Node_Checker = "false"]
//my:Master_Node[../my:Repeater/my:Sub_Node_Checker = "false"]
```

Comment: Jens, the `//my:Master_Node[..//my:Sub_Node_Checker = "false"]` works when I have the exact structure I posted initially. I've expanded my question just a bit as I may have left out some important details. And thank you!

Comment: Yes, you definitely missed important information. :) I'm still not sure about how the predicate should look like. How to decide whether to include the master node or not? Must all node checkers be false, or only one of them? Could there be none at all? Does the master node also repeat?

Comment: If current `../my:Repeater/my:Sub_Node_Checker` equals `false` then set `../my:Repeater/my:Sub_Node` equal to `//my:Master_Node`. If current `../my:Repeater/my:Sub_Node_Checker` equals `true` then set `../my:Repeater/my:Sub_Node` equal to `self`. If you have InfoPath installed then take a look [at this XSN template file](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/storage/41/91044/Conditional_Node_Copy.xsn). I believe it will be more clear if you can look at the template.

Comment: Still don't get you. Anyway: You cannot modify the document using XPath, you also cannot construct new elements to return, all you can do is select nodes. All you can do is select nodes to further process outside XPath.

Comment: Jens, you are correct. I think that InfoPath somehow uses the XPath expression to select the value inside of a specified node; it's as though InfoPath specifies the context node by setting the XPath expression as the default value for that node in the data source. InfoPath's handling of Xpath expressions still somewhat mystifies me. Thanks again for the help! I got it sorted out using a very different method...

Answer (score 1):

Relating to your xpath question you may try something like this.

```
(self::*[../my:Sub_Node_Checker = "true"] 
|
//my:Master_Node)[last()]
```

Which should work if `Master_Node` is always before `Sub_Node` (in document order).

Comment: Thank you! I wish that I could use it but InfoPath does not allow the position function.

Comment: That is strange (InfoPath 2003 seems to support [last](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/functions-in-infopath-HP001155281.aspx) ). May be you can replace the last () function  with count() with the same expression again

Comment: Yeah - no "position" or "last" unfortunately. It's strange because `boolean(..//my:Sub_Node_Checker = "false")` always returns appropriately in InfoPath, but `//my:Master_Node[..//my:Sub_Node_Checker = "false"]` always seems to evaluate the last existing instance of `Sub_Node_Checker`. My XSN Template is attached at [the following link](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/26222/91044.aspx#91044)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got this one worked out a bit differently than my original approach. [The following article on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2006/11/27/conditional-default-values.aspx) has an example of using the `substring()` function to return different values based on outside conditions. Also have to thank Hilary Stoupa at InfoPath Dev for [helping me come to the solution](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/26222/91096.aspx#91096).

I will also mention that I could not use the "current" node and had to create a third node which housed my XPath expression and evaluated the conditions to return the appropriate value.

Here is the source XML roughly as InfoPath might interpret it (note the "location" of the xpath expression in the 3rd `repeater` group - this is how InfoPath evaluates default values):

```
<my:myFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2013-07-02T14:58:05" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-us">
<my:Master_Node>123456</my:Master_Node>
<my:Repeater>
    <my:Sub_Node_Checker>true</my:Sub_Node_Checker>
    <my:Sub_Node>9870</my:Sub_Node>
    <my:Sub_Node_Stored>9870</my:Sub_Node_Stored>
</my:Repeater>
<my:Repeater>
    <my:Sub_Node_Checker>false</my:Sub_Node_Checker>
    <my:Sub_Node></my:Sub_Node>
    <my:Sub_Node_Stored>123456</my:Sub_Node_Stored>
</my:Repeater><
my:Repeater>
    <my:Sub_Node_Checker>false</my:Sub_Node_Checker>
    <my:Sub_Node></my:Sub_Node>
    <my:Sub_Node_Stored>concat(substring(../../my:Master_Node, 1, (../my:Sub_Node_Checker != "true") * string-length(../../my:Master_Node)), substring(../my:Sub_Node, 1, (../my:Sub_Node_Checker != "false") * string-length(../my:Sub_Node)))</my:Sub_Node_Stored>
</my:Repeater>
</my:myFields>
```

Note that the following XPath expression was instrumental in causing the appropriate node to be selected:

```
concat(substring(../../my:Master_Node, 1, (../my:Sub_Node_Checker != "true") * string-length(../../my:Master_Node)), substring(../my:Sub_Node, 1, (../my:Sub_Node_Checker != "false") * string-length(../my:Sub_Node)))
```

The substring function returns the number of characters from the target string as specified by the user. When a boolean value is evaluated inside the substring function (at the location given for number of characters to return) it returns either a "1" or a "0".

When multiplied by the length of the target string this boolean check causes any conditions that would exempt a particular target node from selection to return a length of "0" characters from that node. (0*X=0) This effectively allows for different default values within the node without the use of the `|` operator.